# How can I get the last visible Listitem of an scrollable Container by Scroll-Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When scroll-event fires, I want to get the last shown Listitem (also nested Listitems) from scrollable Container:

[image: Scoll Container]

On every ScrollEvent, it should be selected via jQuery:

```
$('#ScrollContainer').scroll(function() {

    // get last visible Listitem in ScrollContainer

});
```

Looking for fast and simple solution to get it.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5b49/2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#ScrollContainer').scroll(function() {
    var liHeight = $(this).find('li').eq(0).outerHeight();
    var sctrollToBottom =  $(this)[0].scrollTop + $(this).innerHeight()-$(this).find('li').eq(0)[0].offsetTop;
    var lastItemNum = parseInt(sctrollToBottom/liHeight);
    var lastItem = $(this).find('li').eq(lastItemNum);
});
```

Not the most elegant approach. You may be able to optimize.